# Send JSON from one component to another using routing and not display on URL?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to pass JSON on routing URL here is my

app.route.ts code

```
 {path: 'calculator', component: CalculatorComponent,data : {some_data : null}},
```

and my code to route the data is

```
 this.router.navigate(['/home/calculator',  {some_data:this.loanData}]);
```

and the calculator.ts have the oninit method code is like this

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    sub
    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route
            .data
            .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
    }
```

output is like this

> {"some_data":null}

the problem is it's not showing the json, I passed from the ts first component

Comment: In route params you should only pass data that you want to be reflected in the browser URL bar. router data is only for static data. You can not send different data to the same route it always has to be the same.use a shared service for this use case.

Comment: can you explain or send me reference link because i don't know about it

Comment: In Angular 5, anyway, you should be able to ... ngOnInit() { this.myVar = this.route.snapshot.data['some_data']; }

Comment: Make sure you use `$router.current.params` or `$routeParams` if you want to grab these values in the router, as described on [AngularjS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples)

Comment: check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NpLKAgY3FkzhOK9eBeIb?p=preview)

Comment: i am using angular 4

Comment: @fatemefazli so I have to create seperate service for that?

Comment: yes. components can relate each other with a shared service.

Comment: so once i set data on service it's work like rootScope ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Is there a reason you want to navigate by url why not use the navigate method like this:

    in RouteConf: { path: '/path/:data', name: 'Defined_Path_Name', component: PathComponent }
    navigate with: this.router.navigate(['Defined_Path_Name', { data: { entity: 'entity' } } ]);

    in /path: console.log(this.routeParams.get('data'))
    that got me: Object {entity: "entity"}

//in your route file 

 in RouteConf: {path: 'calculator/:data', component: CalculatorComponent},

//in your component file navigate by like below

 navigate with: this.router.navigate(['/calculator', { data: this.loaddata } ]);

//and get data in  /calculator path like 

this.data =  this.route.snapshot.data['data'];

than console.log(this.data);
```

Comment: can you please explain your code and where i have to put this code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this, this should work, hope so

app.route.ts code

```
{path: 'calculator', component: CalculatorComponent},
```

and your code to route

```
 let someData = {
   this.loanData
 };
 this.router.navigate(['/home/calculator/'+someData]);
```

and the calculator.ts have the oninit method code is like this

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    sub
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params
        .subscribe(data => {
         this.sub = data;
          console.log(this.sub);
});
    }
```

Comment: error means it's showing only [object,object] no any other value i am able to find

Comment: check what is in "this.sub" first, may be you have value there, check the value first.